# ArcGis Cemetery Mapping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, references

Im currently doing a cemetery mapping system for my thesis using arcgis, however i dont know how to use arcgis, i dont quite get the tutorials that i watch, i just want to make a simple map that can store the information of each person and search them.

Do you know any tutorials or know how to do so yourself related to this topic?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start with the [Learn ArcGIS](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/) website and in particular, have a look at the lesson on ArcMap.

https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/get-started-with-arcmap/